# "Container" classes, good or bad practice, why?

Tags: java

I'm curious as to which is the better practice and the reasoning behind it, for this example I'm going to be using a social application which contains a 'friends' and a 'ignore' list with some custom logic based on them, (For sending messages directly, etc)

Which would be the better practice, and why?

**Scenario 1**:

```
class user {
    List<> friends;
    List<> ignores;
    ...
    logical methods here
}
```

**Scenario 2**:

```
class User {
     Social social;
     ...
}
class Social {
    List<> friends;
    List<> ignores;
    ...
    logical methods here
}
```

I've seen both scenarios used throughout numerous applications and I'm curious as to which is the "Correct" way to lay it out in java, these will have methods such as

```
#addFriend(User user)
    check ignore
    check valid user
    check other info
    add to list
end

   #getFriend(int id)
        find friend by id
        check online status
   return friend
```

It seems like while have a 'Social' class may be a cleaner approach, does it really follow good practices? Seems like it'd use more memory/user just for cleaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you have such constructs as your `Social`, most of the time, is that they represent a logical set of data and operations which is needed for different entities in your application.

If nothing other than `User` has those properties and actions, then there is no point in doing it separately from `User`. But you may design it separately anyway, for future uses (for example, if you want to be able to expand it later and you believe there will be other entities which will need `Social` functionality).

Looking at this from an object-oriented viewpoint, it means that the `Social` is a type. And then you have to ask yourself, is whether your `User` *is_a* `Social` or whether your `User` *has_a* `Social`. Does it make sense to say that the user has a "social subsystem" or is the user a "social object"? If the correct relation is *is_a*, then `User` should *extend* `Social`. If not, it should have a `Social` member, such as you described.

However, in Java, since you can't have multiple inheritance of implementation, sometimes your type may inherit from several types, and you have to decide which of them to *extend*. Many times, you simulate multiple inheritance of implementation, by having a member of what should have been the "second parent class", declare all the methods in your class, and delegate them to that member.

So the general guidelines are, more or less:

- If in your application's domain, the only class where it will make sense to have `friends` and `ignores` and their operations is `User`, and no other conceivable entity would ever need them, then implement them directly in `User`.
- If other entities may need similar functionality, and not all of them extend `User` anyway, you may consider this functionality to be an entity or class in its own right, and then you should have every class which has an *is_a* relationship to this entity extend it.
- If Java's limitations of multiple inheritance don't allow extending directly, as it makes more sense for the class to extend some other class, you should embed an object and delegate the operations.

There may be other practical reasons to separate the `Social` entity from `User`, despite `User` being the only class to use them. For example, if you have several different possible implementations of "social" behavior, you may want to be able to use various `Social` subclasses as "plug-ins" inside `User`, rather than subclassing `User`.

Comment: Very in depth, great answer, just to verify what I just read, if the only class accessing the `Social` class is the `User` class, and the `User` should NOT extend `Social` then I should just put all of the contents of `Social` inside of the `User` class, correct?

Comment: Yes, unless you have practical considerations such as the one I mentioned in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about memory so early. Go for readable/cleaner code. Premature optimization is root of all evil.

Answer (score 1):

This is really based on the logic of your program. But consider that increasing the number of classes unnecessarily, is not good practice.

In your example, if the User  class only contains a Social field, and you will just delegate all the method calls to the Social class, then go with scenario one.

On the other hand, if the User class has many more fields, like name, date of joining ... then it would be even better to create a separate class for such fields such as UserInfo in order to better structure  your program and enhance code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Now the main concerns are not the memory or performance costs of class structure.

Way more important are readability and clean code, AND the possibility to persist domain classes in a DB in the most simple and efficient way.

The later include `composition or aggregation` concern which is specific for different DB's.

Answer (score 0):

You should care  about the design aspects becoz with this you will have maintainable,scalable  and readable code.

Now going by your example , i find second scenario as good case as it follows the SRP(Single Responsibilty Principle)

Don't worry about memory here as it wont make iota of difference here.

Answer (score 0):

So do you want to do something like:

```
for(Connection connection : userSocialConnections ){
sendMessageTo(connection);
}
```

If so, then the method sendMessageTo would need to accept a connection (friend or ignored, basically a user) and probably if the runtype connection is ignored (or has blocked the user) then the sendMessageTo will return without sending a message polymorphically. This would require that in java that the IgnoredPeople And Friends are subtypes of something called as Connection(or people or anything you like; in fact, a connection is also a user - current or potential, isn't it?). This approach seems  (to me) more like thinking in problem domain. Storing as two list inside user or inside social inside user does not matter much as long as they both (ignored and friends) have a common interface.

I would ask, what all other scenarios can be there for user's friends or ignored list. Do they need to be loaded lazily or stored separately.

Comment: The only time that I'd loop through the connections is to send the "update" packet at login, in which i'd do `getFriends().forEach(f->{ Packet.send(PackType.TCP, getConnection(), packetId, f.getName(), f.getStatus()); });` Where a 'Friend' would be a class containing information, and not just a `connection`

Comment: @Christian.tucker loop is not important. My point is that do they display similar behavior - in this case that related to message. If they share common interface then in boolean terms, they just have different boolean value for isFriend. As such how you store won't matter whether you have container class or not. Containers are not good or evil. I meant something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/27229663/668951